# Change the return type of an implemented interface of a class thru the Metadata.xml (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, metadata, aar

I've bound a new *.aar library to my Xamarin.Forms Project following this guide from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar. After compiling, I get some errors that can be handled using the metadata.xml (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata). But unfortunatelly I haven't found any way how to change the return type of an implemented interface in one of my classes. So here is my issue:

One of the errors after building the aar lib:

> "IIterable.Iterator()". "IteratorImpl.Iterator()" does not have the appropriate return >type "IIterator" and therefore cannot implement "IIterable.Iterator()".

After binding and compiling... my class looks like this:

```
public partial class IteratorImpl : global::Java.Lang.IIterable, global::Java.Util.IIterator
```

But it should be (see the first interface):

```
public partial class IteratorImpl : global::Java.Lang.Iterator, global::Java.Util.IIterator
```

My question: Is there a way to target in the METADATA.XML file the **FIRST** implemented interface (in my class) and change its return type from Java.Lang.IIterable to Java.Lang.Iterator?

Thanks a lot in advance. ☺

Comment: Are you saying that the source code of the `.aar` indicate that the class *does* implement `Iterator` interface? That the building or binding process did not correctly infer the class's signature?

Comment: Worst case, maybe there is some way via metadata.xml to *remove* the failing `global::Java.Lang.Iterator` inheritance? Just keep `IIterator`. Then if needed, manually write a wrapper class to provide `Iterator` support. Is there an `api.xml` file (or similar), that represents that class inheritance in xml? If so, please add that part of xml to the question.

Comment: Hi @ToolmakerSteve, thanks a lot for your fast answer. The second fact is the problem: The building or binding process did not correctly infer the class's signature.

Comment: Hi @ToolmakerSteve Unfortunately I don't have any api.xml in my test project. See the project structure here: [Link](https://www.denis-dominguez.de/maptrip/MapTripAPI_Lib_Aufbau.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with the details of this. Looking at [java bindings metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata), see if you can find a way to generate xml representing the bindings ("api.xml" in that doc). If so, then perhaps that will show some `attribute` that can be modified to get the result you need.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve np. I found a solution and I'm going to post it. Thanks a lot for you time!

Answer (score 1):

**So, I solved the problem by asking a friend that added this library before.**

For those of you trying to link the MapTripAPI.aar from infoware in your Xamarin.Forms(Android) project. Here is the context you must place in the configuration xml METADATA file under the transforms directory. That solved my issue. Now I can build the library and link the API from my project:

```
<metadata>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='de.infoware.android.api']/class[@name='Handle']/method[@name='getHandle' and count(parameter)=0]" name="visibility">public</attr>
        <attr path="/api/package[@name='de.infoware.android.api']/class[@name='Log']/field[@name='LOG']" name="name">LOG_Binding</attr>
        <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.universalchardet.prober.contextanalysis']/class[@name='JapaneseContextAnalysis.Order']/field[@name='order']" name="name">Order_Binding</attr>
        <attr path="/api/package[@name='de.infoware.android.api']/class[@name='IteratorImpl']/method[@name='iterator' and count(parameter)=0]" name="managedReturn">Java.Util.IIterator</attr>
        <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.spongycastle.crypto.tls']/interface[@name='TlsSigner']" name="name">ITlsSigner</attr>
        <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.spongycastle.math.ec']/interface[@name='ECMultiplier']" name="name">IECMultiplier</attr>
        <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.spongycastle.math.ec']/interface[@name='PreCompInfo']" name="name">IPreCompInfo</attr>
        <attr path="/api/package[@name='de.infoware.android.api']/class[@name='IwApiThread']" name="visibility">public</attr>
    
        <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='de.infoware.android.api']/class[@name='LaneInfoHelper.LaneArrow']"/>
        <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='de.infoware.android.api']/class[@name='LaneInfoHelper.LaneDivider']"/>
        <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='de.infoware.android.api']/class[@name='LaneInfoHelper.LaneObject']"/>
    
        <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.iw_universalchardet.prober.contextanalysis']/class[@name='JapaneseContextAnalysis.Order']/field[@name='order']"/>
    </metadata>
```